# Different runtime for svm and ranger using the same task

Tags: r, svm, mlr, mlr3, r-ranger

I've bench-marked the runtime of the two learners and also took two screenshots of the {htop} while {ranger} and {svm} was training to make my point more clearer. As stated in the title of this post, my question is the reason Why train/predict in svm is so slow compare to other learners (in this case ranger)? Is it related to the underlying structure of the learners? Or I am making a mistake in the code? Or...? Any help is appreciated.

[image: htop when ranger is training]
htop when ranger is training; all threads are used.

[image: htop when svm is training]
htop when svm is training; only 2 threads are used.

code:

```r
library(mlr3verse)

library(future.apply)
#> Loading required package: future
library(future)
library(lgr)
library(data.table)

file <- 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3ao-SOFH/view?usp=sharing' 
#you can download the file using this link.
destfile = '/../Downloads/sample.RData'
download.file(file, destfile)


# pre-processing
sample$clc3_red <- as.factor(sample$clc3_red)
sample$X <- NULL
#> Warning in set(x, j = name, value = value): Column 'X' does not exist to remove
sample$confidence <- NULL
sample$ecoregion_id <- NULL
sample$gsw_occurrence_1984_2019 <- NULL

tsk_clf <- mlr3::TaskClassif$new(id = 'sample', backend = sample, target = "clc3_red")
tsk_clf$col_roles$group = 'tile_id' #spatial CV
tsk_clf$col_roles$feature = setdiff(tsk_clf$col_roles$feature ,  'tile_id')
tsk_clf$col_roles$feature = setdiff(tsk_clf$col_roles$feature ,  'x')
tsk_clf$col_roles$feature = setdiff(tsk_clf$col_roles$feature ,  'y')

# 2 learners for benchmarking
svm <- lrn("classif.svm", type = "C-classification", kernel = "radial", predict_type = "response")
ranger <- lrn("classif.ranger", predict_type = "response", importance = "permutation")

# ranger parallel
plan(multicore)
time <- Sys.time()
ranger$
  train(tsk_clf)$
  predict(tsk_clf)$
  score()
#> Warning: Dropped unused factor level(s) in dependent variable: 333, 335, 521,
#> 522.
#> classif.ce 
#>     0.0116
Sys.time() - time
#> Time difference of 20.12981 secs

# svm parallel
plan(multicore)
time <- Sys.time()
svm$
  train(tsk_clf)$
  predict(tsk_clf)$
  score()
#> classif.ce 
#>     0.4361
Sys.time() - time
#> Time difference of 55.13694 secs
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#> Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#> Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
#> LAPACK: /opt/microsoft/ropen/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so
#> 
#> locale:
#>  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
#>  [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#>  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#>  [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
#>  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#> [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] data.table_1.12.8   lgr_0.3.4           future.apply_1.6.0 
#>  [4] future_1.18.0       mlr3verse_0.1.3     paradox_0.3.0      
#>  [7] mlr3viz_0.1.1       mlr3tuning_0.1.2    mlr3pipelines_0.1.3
#> [10] mlr3learners_0.2.0  mlr3filters_0.2.0   mlr3_0.3.0         
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.5         compiler_4.0.2     pillar_1.4.6       highr_0.8         
#>  [5] class_7.3-17       mlr3misc_0.3.0     tools_4.0.2        digest_0.6.25     
#>  [9] uuid_0.1-4         lattice_0.20-41    evaluate_0.14      lifecycle_0.2.0   
#> [13] tibble_3.0.3       checkmate_2.0.0    gtable_0.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3   
#> [17] rlang_0.4.7        Matrix_1.2-18      parallel_4.0.2     yaml_2.2.1        
#> [21] xfun_0.15          e1071_1.7-3        ranger_0.12.1      withr_2.2.0       
#> [25] stringr_1.4.0      knitr_1.29         globals_0.12.5     vctrs_0.3.2       
#> [29] grid_4.0.2         glue_1.4.1         listenv_0.8.0      R6_2.4.1          
#> [33] rmarkdown_2.3      ggplot2_3.3.2      magrittr_1.5       mlr3measures_0.2.0
#> [37] codetools_0.2-16   backports_1.1.8    scales_1.1.1       htmltools_0.5.0   
#> [41] ellipsis_0.3.1     colorspace_1.4-1   stringi_1.4.6      munsell_0.5.0     
#> [45] crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 3):

It is totally expected that an SVM runs longer than a random forest since SVMs scale badly with increasing number of observations and number of features.
Things that make SVM more expensive:

- Multiclass: here, for each class one SVM is trained, because SVM natively can just solve binary classification
- Many categorical variables inflate the number of features as they are converted to numerical features through dummy encoding

There are approximate SVMs that are faster, but it's usually not worth to investigate further since they are often outperformed by tree based approaches (random forest) or boosting approaches (xgboost).

See also: [Why does my SVM take so long to run?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345717/why-does-my-svm-take-so-long-to-run) and [How much time does take train SVM classifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18165213/how-much-time-does-take-train-svm-classifier)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @jakob-r. I understand your points, however since {SVMs} was among top classifier on my bench-marking experience (please see the graph [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WFAj1dupJ9G5Sug2sBxejeu8sjTTDKFB/view?usp=sharing)) I'd like to consider it on my ensemble  design. However, the computational cost of {SVMs} is the bottleneck and I was hoping to use parallelization approach to reduce the cost. Will `future` or similar packages be of help when using {SVMs}? If yes, I appreciate if you let me know.

Comment: As @pat-s mentioned. You can only parallelize the resampling for speedup. I am not aware of any SVM implementation that uses parallelization. I can only imagine that theoretically multiclass-SVM can be parallelized because it trains multiple SVMs internally for each class.

Comment: Then, would you please guide me with how to  parallelized resampling process (in this case for ensemble approach which involves {SVMs}) using mlr3?

Comment: Did you have a look here: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/parallelization.html

Comment: Yes, I implemented the approach in the link with ensemble setting (which again involves {SVMs}), however it didn't really help to speed up the process (to parallelized the resampling) considering ensemble, as I also mentioned it [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65291768/parallelization-on-resampling-within-a-stacked-learner-ensemble-stack-of-classi/65379777?noredirect=1#comment115693073_65379777).

Comment: mlr3 parallelization is well tested and documented. Following the docs should get you going. You will still see longer SVM runtimes compared to ranger for the reasons shown above. We are going around in circles a bit here. If you really struggle to set up parallelization with mlr3 despite reading the docs, please post a new question. You might want to reconsider your SVM learner choice for your dataset if runtime is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In a simple train/predict call you are not making use of any mlr3 related parallelization. What you see for `ranger` is internal baked-in parallelization (which e1071 does not have). See the `num.threads` argument in `ranger::ranger()`.

To make use of mlr3 related parallelization you need to either

- tune hyperparameters
- run a cross-validation (i.e. multiple train/predict calls)
- benchmark multiple learners

The single `train()` calls which perform the direct model fit are not touched by mlr3.
Usually its good to keep it like this because they are quite fast and enabling built-in learner parallelization might cause hickups with future-based parallelization.

I haven't taken a look at your dataset but seeing the fitting time for a single model fit, it might/must be quite large.
SVM optimizes lambda and C by default IIRC and that's why you might see the rather large fitting time for SVM here.

Comment: Thanks @pat-s. I have tried {svm} in all the above-mentioned scenarios (i.e., tuning, cv, bm), however, it's runtime was very large and not comparable with other learners (I can make a reprex here, however I think it is a bit redundant). I'd like to ask you if you have any suggestion(s) for me regrading {svm's} runtime optimization and more specifically when it is used in an ensemble approach together with other learners? Am I missing something in the code?